# I can not figure out how to pass a REST response object to a ReactJS child component correctly

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, rest, reactjs

What I am trying to do.

I want to setup a `multi select list box` so that a user can set a list of `test cases` which belong to the parent `test suite`.

To do this I have created a `component` which shows the details for the `test suite`.  Within that I have then created another `component` to take the current list of `test cases` and an available list of `test cases` they could select from.

When processing the components I make a `REST` `HTTP GET` call to get the `test suite`'s currently assigned `test cases`.

I am having a issue on how to set the data for the lower component to use.

When defining the `ListBoxWidget` I am unable to set the selectedListObjects correctly because at the time of the initial render the state object is empty.  The `REST` call to populate the components is within `componentDidMount` is in the process of being called but react continues to render the components.

```
                            <ListBoxWidget
                              unselectedListObjects={unselectedListObjects}
                                selectedListObjects={this.state.selectedListObjects} />
```

Within `ListBoxWidget` when I go to set the state initially it is set to nothing since there is no value yet.

**Question**

1) How should I be setting the initial value of a input element?

2) Should I be setting the way that `ListBoxWidget` gets its initial value differently and not through the state?  I could not see how to do this and have the onChange work correctly.

My other thought is to rewrite the underlying NPM 'react-dual-listbox' class so that I can try to use `defaultValue=` on the `<select>` but I do not know if that is allowed in React.

**Solution:  I added the ability to wait for rendering until the selectedListObjects state is set.**

```
{this.props.objectName == "Test Suite" && this.state.selectedListObjects != null &&
            <ListBoxWidget
              unselectedListObjects={unselectedListObjects}
              selectedListObjects={this.state.selectedListObjects} />
```

Thank you

Here is the code:

UpdateDialog.js  (note I have removed some areas of this)

```
class UpdateDialog extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {selectedListObjects: [], unselectedListObjects: []};
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.setupTestSuite = this.setupTestSuite.bind(this);
  }

  onChange(selected) {
    this.setState({ selected });
  }

  setupTestSuite() {
    var testCasesHref = this.props.object.entity._links.testCases.href;
    console.log("this.props.object.entity._links.testCases.href " + testCasesHref)
    // we need to make a call to get all of the test cases


    var selectedListObjects = [];

    client({
      method: 'GET',
      path: testCasesHref
    })........ // set the selected objects in the state
      this.setState({
        selectedListObjects: selectedListObjects
      });
    });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("calling componentDidMount in update");

    if (this.props.objectName == "Test Suite") {
      this.setupTestSuite();
    }
  }

  render() {

    var dialogId = "updateObject-" + this.props.object.entity._links.self.href;

    var listObjects;
    var selectedListObjects;

    var unselectedListObjects = [
          { value: "http://localhost:8081/api/testCases/1", label: 'Test Case 1' },
          { value: "http://localhost:8081/api/testCases/2", label: 'Test Case 2' },
          { value: "http://localhost:8081/api/testCases/3", label: 'Test Case 3' },
          { value: "http://localhost:8081/api/testCases/4", label: 'Test Case 4' },
        ];


            var selectedListObjects = ["http://localhost:8081/api/testCases/1"];  // NOTE if I set this it will take the value
    console.log("setting up render for update dialog with state " + this.state.selectedListObjects);

    return (
      <div>

            <form>
              {inputs}
              {this.props.objectName == "Test Suite" &&
                <ListBoxWidget
                  unselectedListObjects={unselectedListObjects}
                  selectedListObjects={this.state.selectedListObjects} />
              }
              <button onClick={this.handleSubmit}>Update</button>
            </form>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    )
  }

}

module.exports = UpdateDialog
```

Note: I have included var selectedListObjects in the render, if this is used to set the value for the selected list instead of from the state it works but this is because it does not need to make a call to get the actual values and is defined within the initial render.

```
    var selectedListObjects = ["http://localhost:8081/api/testCases/1"];  // NOTE if I set this it will take the value
```

ListBoxWidget.js

```
'use strict';

const React = require('react');

// import components
const DualListBox = require('react-dual-listbox');

class ListBoxWidget extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        console.log("**** calling to set state in constructor with " + this.props.selectedListObjects);
        this.state = { selected: this.props.selectedListObjects };
        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    }

    onChange(selected) {
        this.setState({ selected });
    }

    componentDidMount() {
      console.log("---- calling mount ");
    }

    render() {

        console.log("render in list box widget");

        console.log("this.state.selected inside widget-"+this.state.selected+"-");
        console.log("this.props.selectedListObjects inside widget-"+this.props.selectedListObjects+"-");

        return (
          <DualListBox
            name="Test Cases"
            options={this.props.unselectedListObjects}
            preserveSelectOrder
            selected={this.props.selectedListObjects}
            onChange={this.onChange} />

        )
    }
}

module.exports = ListBoxWidget
```

Console output:

```
UpdateDialog.js:108 setting up render for update dialog with state 
ListBoxWidget.js:11 **** calling to set state in constructor with 
ListBoxWidget.js:26 render in list box widget
ListBoxWidget.js:28 this.state.selected inside widget--
ListBoxWidget.js:29 this.props.selectedListObjects inside widget--
UpdateDialog.js:108 setting up render for update dialog with state 
ListBoxWidget.js:11 **** calling to set state in constructor with 
ListBoxWidget.js:26 render in list box widget
ListBoxWidget.js:28 this.state.selected inside widget--
ListBoxWidget.js:29 this.props.selectedListObjects inside widget--
ListBoxWidget.js:21 ---- calling mount 
UpdateDialog.js:78 calling componentDidMount in update
UpdateDialog.js:41 this.props.object.entity._links.testCases.href http://localhost:8081/api/testSuites/1/testCases
ListBoxWidget.js:21 ---- calling mount 
UpdateDialog.js:78 calling componentDidMount in update
UpdateDialog.js:41 this.props.object.entity._links.testCases.href http://localhost:8081/api/testSuites/2/testCases
UpdateDialog.js:57 objectMap
UpdateDialog.js:58 [Promise, Promise]
UpdateDialog.js:57 objectMap
UpdateDialog.js:58 [Promise]
UpdateDialog.js:63 objects
UpdateDialog.js:64 [Object, Object]
UpdateDialog.js:65 calling for each
UpdateDialog.js:67 testCase._links.self.hrefhttp://localhost:8081/api/testCases/1
UpdateDialog.js:67 testCase._links.self.hrefhttp://localhost:8081/api/testCases/3
UpdateDialog.js:108 setting up render for update dialog with state http://localhost:8081/api/testCases/1,http://localhost:8081/api/testCases/3
ListBoxWidget.js:26 render in list box widget
ListBoxWidget.js:28 this.state.selected inside widget--
ListBoxWidget.js:29 this.props.selectedListObjects inside widget-http://localhost:8081/api/testCases/1,http://localhost:8081/api/testCases/3-
UpdateDialog.js:63 objects
UpdateDialog.js:64 [Object]
UpdateDialog.js:65 calling for each
UpdateDialog.js:67 testCase._links.self.hrefhttp://localhost:8081/api/testCases/1
UpdateDialog.js:108 setting up render for update dialog with state http://localhost:8081/api/testCases/1
ListBoxWidget.js:26 render in list box widget
ListBoxWidget.js:28 this.state.selected inside widget--
ListBoxWidget.js:29 this.props.selectedListObjects inside widget-http://localhost:8081/api/testCases/1-
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you made it correctly by using state and `componentDidMount` to fetch and populate it with initial data - no problems here. The issue with child control you can overcome in two ways:

1. If you have possibility to rewrite control - make it so it can handle absence of `selectedListObjects` property and render itself without selection or with first object selected - whatever is more appropriate in your case.
2. Do not render ListBoxWidget in parent `render` until you will fetch the data in `componentDidMount`. Check if `this.state.selectedListObjects` is undefined - skip rendering ListBoxWidget, or render instead of it stub with waiting icon to show user that data is being loaded.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I just gave number 2 a shot and it worked perfectly. I didnt think of that for some reason.  Also how do you setup the ability to have the waiting icon until its rendered? Is there a particular npm library to use for it? Thank you

Comment: You are welcome. The simplest way would be to render same size grayed div with centered animated icon inside (examples of nice waiting icons: https://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/examples/).